# Fitting sigmoid to data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

There are many curve fitting and interpolation tools like polyfit (or even this nice logfit toolbox I found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29545-power-law-exponential-and-logarithmic-fit)), but I can't seem to find anything that will fit a `sigmoid` function to my x-y data.

Does such a tool exist or do I need to make my own?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox installed, you can use [nonlinear regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-1.html) with [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html):

```
sigfunc = @(A, x)(A(1) ./ (A(2) + exp(-x)));
A0 = ones(size(A)); %// Initial values fed into the iterative algorithm
A_fit = nlinfit(x, y, sigfunc, A0);
```

Here `sigfunc` is just an example for a sigmoid function, and `A` is the vector of the fitting coefficients.

Comment: I found the following sigfunc to be more useful `sigfunc = @(A, x)(A(1) ./ (1 + exp(-A(2)*x)));`

Comment: @user92519 No problem, I only gave this as an example.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by `vector of the fitting coefficients`?

Comment: @ShohamDebnath what I mean is that vector `A` is the vector of coefficients that defines the fitted sigmoid. To clarfiy that, you can look at the definition of `sigfunc`.

Answer (score 9):

`nlinfit`, and especially `gatool`, are big hammers for this problem. A sigmoid is not a specific function. Most commonly it is taken to be the same as the logistic function (also often the most efficient to calculate):

```
y = 1./(1+exp(-x));
```

or a generalized logistic. But all manner of curves can have [sigmoidal shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples). If you know if your data corresponds to one in particular, fitting can be improved and more efficient methods can be applied. For example, the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (`erf`) has a sigmoidal shape and shows up in the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_distribution). If you know that your data is the result of a Gaussian process (i.e., the data is the CDF) and you have the Stats toolbox, you can use the `normfit` function. This function is based on [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) (MLE). If you end up needing to write a custom fitting function - say, for performance reasons - I'd investigate MLE techniques for the particular form of sigmoid that you'd like to fit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use MATLAB's [Global Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/), and in particular the [Genetic Algorithm Solver](http://www.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/description4.html), which you can use for your problem by optimizing (= finding the best fit for your data) the sigmoid function's parameters through genetic algorithm. It has a GUI that is easy to use.

The [Genetic Algorithm Solver](http://www.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/description4.html)'s GUI, which you can call using `gatool`:
[image]